# What kind of demons and/or beasts can cause impact in a population of the Inca empire in its respective period?

Tags: magic

My main character fights against various types of beasts in their territories. I always mention their physical appearance and the description is always the same for all of them.

How would I best describe them? Is there some kind of beast which would be able to impact people of the Inca empire as well as the reader?

*I'm taking in account that the events which have occurred in [Inca mythology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inca_mythology) are in here depicted as real events.

[This was an attempted translation from spanish to english. Feel free to improve it, should there be any kind of error which I've failed to notice.]

Comment: If my Google Translate is functioning, then your question is too broad :D More people would be able to tell if you were to ask it in English

Comment: Bienvenido a Worldbuilding SE. Preferimos que las preguntas se hagan en inglés; alguien puede ofrecer una edición para proporcionar una traducción. Tal como está, su pregunta se refiere a su estilo de escritura, más que al mundo, y es probable que se suspenda como fuera de tema. (Traducción a través de Google Translate.)

Comment: @Frostfyre, I'm not a fan of Google translate (I speak Finnish, and Google's translation of Finnish... well, it reeks...). Would you be comfortable drawing a line under the OP's post and providing an English translation?

Comment: @JBH My Spanish isn't strong enough to _not_ use G-Translate.

Answer (score 2):

(I hope its alright that this answer is in English)

Your questions rather broad, so it would be helpful to narrow down the subject a little (like for example by listing what specific demons/beasts your thinking of) and defining limits to what are supernatural entities.

If your using actual mythological beings than do their powers map directly being the same in your story as in the mythology? Likewise what is the "logic" of your story? Is it a kind of "alt-history" world or is it more mythological like?

I hope this was a bit helpful, sorry I couldn't provide the exact answer/s your were looking for. But hopefully this will help you make your question more succinct. :)

Comment: It's alright. English is the de facto language for all non-language-specific stacks because (for good or bad), [English is the most spoken language in the world](https://www.indexmundi.com/world/languages.html). What we could use is someone like @Frostfyre to provide an English translation to the question. We're not trying to be exclusive - just practical.

Answer (score 1):

you could start off by doing a search of the 13th century mythology in South America, and detect which of these mythological beings was considered hostile. There is a lot of information about Inca mythology and you can take any of those characters that always have some element of nature as a base (water, volcanoes, rain, fire, etc.) and give them characteristics of an enemy. For that you could use a character template, you find them all over the internet and they will help you give more features to this character.

*ESPAÑOL:
Hola DIVIA29, podrías partir haciendo una búsqueda de la mitología del siglo XIII en sud América, y detectar cuál de estos seres mitológicos era considerado como hostil. Hay mucha información sobre la mitología Inca y puedes tomar cualquiera de  esos personajes que como base siempre tienen algún elemento de la naturaleza (agua, volcanes, lluvia, fuego, etc..) y darles características de un enemigo. Para eso podrías usar una plantilla de personajes, las encuentras por todo internet y te ayudarán a darle mas rasgos a este personaje.*